# Physical interpretation regarding heat equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature, conservation-laws, integration

I have included [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ippsp.jpg)  of a problem from Oxford ( from a Math course).

[image]

I was able to do the question. However, i am stuck at the last part which asks about the physical interpretation. I don't have a good background in physics. Can you please give a hint?

It's about this integral
$$\int_{0}^{L}k\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}(x,y^{*})dx=Lq^{*}.$$
I think that the answer must lie in how the the integral doesn't depend on $y^{*}$. I have this vague notion that perhaps the integral is tantamount to adding up the infinitesimal changes in T (in the y direction) at each x. Since the integral is constant it means that for any y level the total rate of change along y is a constant (although it may vary at within a y at x's, the total result is the same regardless of y).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It implies that the net vertical flow of heat at any elevation y due to the T* part of the solution is zero, and that the net (downward) flow of heat (per unit distance into the paper) is constant at $q^*L$ at all elevations y.  This is because the upward heat flow per unit area is given by $-k\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}$.

Comment: What do you mean by the T* part?

Comment: The solution is the linear superposition of two simpler solutions, one for which T* is zero and the other for which q* is zero.

Answer (score 2):

One possible interpretation could come from noticing that:
$$\frac{1}{L}\int_0^Lf(x)\,dx$$
is the mean value of $f$ on $[0,L]$.

That woud make:
$$\frac{1}{L}\int_0^L\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}(x,y^*)\,dx$$
the mean value of $\partial T/\partial x$ on this interval. That could provide a typical value for the temperature gradient. Multiplied by $k$, that'd be the mean heat flux.